# Recursively fetching data with axios and chaining the result

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have an url of the pattern `http://www.data.com/1`, where the 1 at the end can run up until a not predefined number. It returns an array. I need to concatenate all the arrays I get into one.

My strategy is to recursively perform a get-request, until I get a 404 error, upon which I return the result.

```
var returnArray = [];

function getData(count){
let p = axios.get(`http://www.data.com/${count}`).then(function(response){
  returnArray = returnArray.concat(response.data);
  return getData(count +1);
}
).catch(function() {
    Promise.resolve(returnArray);
}
)};
```

When I implement this function, however, my result is undefined.

```
getData(1).then((response) => console.log(response))
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not sure about the *best way*, but I would go with `async/await` and a `while` loop which runs until it gets 404 response.

Comment: what is `getLeadData`?

Comment: I think function `getLeadData` should return promise also?

Comment: I guess that you return promise `p` from your `getData` function, but because you expect to get the result from `catch` did you try to return this also?: `return Promise.resolve(returnArray);`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to rename the function, `getLeadData` is equal to `getData`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `getData`, you are not returning the promise, so the function immediately exits with undefined value.
So, instead of:

```
let p = axios.get(`http://www.data.com/${count}`).then(function(response){
```

use:

```
return axios.get(`http://www.data.com/${count}`).then(function(response){
```

EDIT: As Bergi pointed out, you also need to return `returnArray` within `catch` handler, so instead of:

```
Promise.resolve(returnArray);
```

use:

```
return returnArray;
```

Here's the full code:

```
var returnArray = [];

function getData(count){
  return axios.get(`http://www.data.com/${count}`).then(function(response){
    returnArray = returnArray.concat(response.data);
    return getData(count +1);
  }
  ).catch(function() {
    return returnArray;
  }
)};
```

Comment: Also `return` the `returnArray` from the `catch` handler

Answer (score 0):

I believe the order of concatanation depends on the count so you have to sequence promises one after the other.

You may do recursive concatanation by increasing the `cnt` argument and accumulating the result in the `rs` argument of the `sp` function up until finally a promise rejects. Once rejected, since all previous resolutions are already concatenated in the `rs` argument, just simply return it in the `catch` stage.

In below code `ps` array resembles an API and `ps[cnt]` resembles a call to the API like;

```
axios.get(`http://www.data.com/${cnt}`);
```

```js
var ps = [new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(v,Math.random()*1000,[0,1,2])),
          new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(v,Math.random()*1000,[3,4,5])),
          new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(v,Math.random()*1000,[6,7,8])),
          new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(x,1000,null))],
    sp = (cnt = 0, rs = []) => ps[cnt].then(vs => sp(++cnt, rs.concat(vs)))
                                      .catch(e => rs);

sp().then(console.log);
```

This method of sequencing of course takes time as every other promise registeres only after the previous one gets resolved. So another way to go could be to batch a group of promise jobs in sub arrays and use these chunks with `Promise.all()`. Which can also be implemented in a similar recursive fashion.